# EJS linting error - remove unnecessary <% and %>

Tags: node.js, webpack, ejs

In our webpack build, we have a file with ejs template:

```
 <% switch (type) {
    case 'homepage' : %>
            <%- include partials/top -%>
            <% break;
    case 'amsterdam' : %>
            <%- include partials/1 -%>
            <% break;
    case 'company' : %>
           <%- include partials/2 -%>
            <% break;
    case 'new york' : %>
            <%- include partials/3 -%>
            <% break;
    case 'paris' : %>
            <%- include partials/4 -%>
            <% break;
    } %>
```

This works. But is it possible to remove all the `<%` and `%>` as the whole block is actually to be interpreted by `<% %>`.

I tried leaving only the first <% and the ending %> as shown below but the build fails suggesting a ejs linting error.

```
<% switch (type) {
    case 'homepage' : 
            include partials/top
            break;
    case 'amsterdam' :
             include partials/1
             break;
    case 'company' : 
             include partials/2 
             break;
    case 'new york' : 
            include partials/3 
            break;
    case 'paris' : 
            include partials/4 
            break;
    } %>
```

Is it possible at all to remove all those `<% %>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<% %> is for conditionnal statement or variable evaluation, to display you have to use <%= %> or <%- %> but those expect a value and not an expression

The only way to do it it's to include your switch in a function and return the result :

```
<% var a  = 1; %>

<%- (function(){
        switch(a){
            case 1:
                return include("c.ejs");
                break;
            case 2:
                return include("d.ejs");
                break;
           default:
               break;
         }

     })()
 %>
```